# How to get value of selected radio button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to give the element `.active-color` the value of the selected radio button.

The text in the `active-color` should change to the selected radio button.
What am I missing?

**The HTML**

```
<div class="swatch">

   <div class="swatch-element schwarz">       
      <div class="tooltip">Schwarz</div>        
      <input id="schwarz" type="radio" name="properties[Farbe]" value="Schwarz" data-image="url({{ 'schwarz.jpg' | asset_url }})" checked="checked">        
      <label for="schwarz"></label>        
   </div>

   <div class="swatch-element weiss">       
      <div class="tooltip">Weiss</div>        
      <input id="weiss" type="radio" name="properties[Farbe]" value="Weiss" data-image="url({{ 'weiss.jpg' | asset_url }})">        
      <label for="weiss"></label>        
   </div>

   <div class="swatch-element chamois">       
      <div class="tooltip">Chamois</div>        
      <input id="chamois" type="radio" name="properties[Farbe]" value="Chamois" data-image="url({{ 'chamois.jpg' | asset_url }})">        
      <label for="chamois"></label>        
   </div>

</div>
<span class="active-color"></span>
```

**And the Function:**

```
jQuery('.active-color').text($(".swatch input:checked").val());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be  the class name `swatch`, it should be `swatch-element`

```
jQuery('.active-color').text($(".swatch-element input:checked").val());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vz9ftsqw/)

Comment: really, `swatch` element was in code, but it wasn't properly displayed. After edit - it's in displayed code)

Comment: @demo yes... so looks like OP had some other problem... but how is this got accepted then?

Comment: @demo might be OP didn't use the change event handler... which I used in the fiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

You are looking input under `swatch` but it is `swatch-element`
so change below line

```
jQuery('.active-color').text($(".swatch input:checked").val());
```

to

```
jQuery('.active-color').text($(".swatch-element input:checked").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this youre are using the wrong class name `swatch` it should be `swatch-element`

```
jQuery('.active-color').text($(".swatch-element input:checked").val());
```